# Facebook sdk how to set two read permission to one

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem that i get two permissions pop up boxes for my app. First one is 
"Explovia would like to access your public profile and friend list" and second one is 
"Explovia would like to access your public profile and friend list, email".

How to set these two to just one? Because second one basicly is asking for same permission as first one + email, is the first permission then realy neccesary ?

```
// Create session and make Request object with all permisssions listed
Session s = new Session(mActivity);
Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity);
request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
request.setCallback(mCallback);
s.openForRead(request);
```

**EDIT**: added callback code

```
private Session.StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API

              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object                    
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                        com.facebook.Response response) {

                    try {

                        editEmail.setText((String) user.getProperty("email").toString());
                    }catch(Exception e){

                        Toast.makeText(mActivity,"We couldn't retrieve your email because you didn't confirm your email!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    editName.setText(user.getFirstName());
                    editSurname.setText(user.getLastName());

                    // We must have try-catch here because if user doesn't have confirmed email, app will crash


                    // Get user id because we will need it later to access 
                    // user profile picture(graph.facebook.com/uId/picture?width=x&height=x)
                    uId = user.getId().toString();
                    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+uId+"/picture?width=200&height=200";


                    imagePhoto.setTag(url);

                    new DownloadImagesTask().execute(imagePhoto);


                    // Delete created session because we don't need it anymore
                    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                    Session.setActiveSession(null);


                }
              });
            }

        }

    };
```

Comment: This code looks fine, but you must be calling the login again somewhere else in the code

Comment: @SahilMittal i added callback function too, did i request for new permission in here maybe?

Comment: This looks fine. You have to place some breakpoints and check in your code where exactly is this happening..

Comment: @SahilMittal, ok i think i found the solution, in Session.openActiveSession(Activity,Boolean,Status.CallBack), i put false in Boolean parameter and now it works. I tried reading some facebook documentation about this parameter and i don't realy understand what i did.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and accept it, so that the discussion may close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i found the solution, in Session.openActiveSession(Activity,Boolean,Status.CallBack), i put false in Boolean parameter and now it works.